# ok to use a same AccessToken to call twitter api concurrently?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I use twitter4j in a twitter client with OAuth. 
The same AccessToken is used to make calls to the api concurrently:
to make calls to get/followers/ids and to get/friends/ids.
As I get quite a few 401 errors during these calls, I wondered if this concurrent use of the same AccessToken was a possible source of the problem?

Notes for clarification:
- the 401 code corresponds to an auth error in theory, but my auth is ok.
- the doc says the twitter4j Twitter object is fit for concurrency, but my question is, even when the same AccessToken is passed to it?

Comment: are you using multiple twitter objects? if so then no you cannot

Comment: thx, much appreciated. Yes I am using multiple twitter objects indeed. Can you elaborate or add a link to explain further?

Comment: not off hand, I would have to search for it and I am sure you can use google as well as I can.

Comment: ok. (I spend a looot of time searching for an answer on Google / SO / Twitter dev forum ...). Anyway, I am refactoring my code so that a single access token is not used concurrently.

Comment: I just don't know off hand. I either used the same twitter object to do multiple things, or different access tokes (ie different accounts)